# How can I plot two lines in the same style (using cycle lists) with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I am using cycle lists and the `\addplot+` command to plot lines in different styles. I would like to plot several things using each style, however, like this:

```
% Plot using style 1
\addplot+ coordinates {...};
\addplot coordinates {...};
\addlegendentry{Style 1}

% Plot using style 2
\addplot+ coordinates {...};
\addplot coordinates {...};
\addlegendentry{Style 2}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`forget plot` key is the usual way to do this but `\addlegendentry{}` does not choose which `addplot` command it comes after. You have to draw the to-be-legended(!?) plots consecutively at the beginning. So you can collate the plots such that you draw them 1-2-3,1-2-3, in terms of style as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
% Plot using style 1
\addplot {ln(x)};\addlegendentry{Style 1}
\addplot {3*x};\addlegendentry{Style 2}

\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-2} % Goes two styles back
\addplot {0.5*x}; %Style 1
\addplot {2*x}; %Style 2
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: be warned: {cycle list shift} is not a function but an offset so it does not affect the internel counter! So to draw another two plots with the same style use \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-4} (and not -2 agian)

Comment: @Thomas That's the designated behavior, from the manual; *Remember that `i` is the index of the current `\addplot` command (starting with 0).*

Answer (score 5):

Never mind, I seem to have stumbled upon the answer myself in the [pfdplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=404) section 4.25 "Miscellaneous Options", specifically the `forget plot` option:

```
% Plot using style 1
\addplot+ [forget plot] coordinates {...};
\addplot+ coordinates {...};
\addlegendentry{Style 1}

% Plot using style 2
\addplot+ [forget plot] coordinates {...};
\addplot+ coordinates {...};
\addlegendentry{Style 2}
```