# Cycle every n plot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have a set of data to plot where I'd like groups of N consecutive plots with the same style. Options I've considered:

- I can define a new `cycle list` by hand
- I can use `forget plot`
- I can use the `cycle list shift` as in [plot two lines in the same style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67772/how-can-i-plot-two-lines-in-the-same-style-using-cycle-lists-with-pgfplots)

Here's an example, with two groups of 3 plots, that does what I want using this last method:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            ]
                    % First group of identical plots
                    \addplot+ [domain=-1:2, samples=10] {1*x+1};
                    \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-1}
                    \addplot+ [domain=-1:2, samples=10] {1*x+2};
                    \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-2}
                    \addplot+ [domain=-1:2, samples=10] {1*x+3};
                    % Second group of identical plots
                    \addplot+ [domain=-1:2, samples=10] {2*x+1};
                    \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-3}
                    \addplot+ [domain=-1:2, samples=10] {2*x+2};
                    \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-4}
                    \addplot+ [domain=-1:2, samples=10] {2*x+3};
                    % and so on... I have a dozen of sets of 5 plots. It would get tedious.
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two groups of three plots]

I'd like something cleaner and automated, maybe with this type of syntax:

```
cycle multi list={%
        color list\nextlist
        [5 of]mark list
}
```

But I can't figure out how!

Edit: I can't figure out either a proper method for building the legend, with only every N plots too.

Comment: I've added the legend in the question... Tell me if you think it should go to a separate post.

Comment: Some doubts: (1) Does all your Groups have the same number of plots? (e.g. in your example there are 2 Groups of 3 plots each). (2) Do you want to do it with `\foreach`? And (3) Are you going to use legends?

Comment: There are **7** `\addplot`s given in the code which give (for me) another resulting image. Please update at least one of them.

Comment: @Guilherme Zanotelli (1) In the case I have, only the last group has a different number of plots. A solution able to handle that would be even better, but I don't mind playing around manually a bit for this special extra-case. (2) `\foreach` is fine, but I thought I'd be easier with cycle list. In the real case, I'm using data from the same text file, `x` axis is the same for every one, and `y` axis is read from different columns, something like `table[x=myX, y=groupID_plotID]` (3) Yes, I use legends, with every N plots wanted in it.

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow you're right, edited.

Comment: @user122824, since you commented both solutions of being useful: Could think of [accepting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) one of the solutions (by clicking on the checkmark ✓ next to the answer) which fits your needs most. By that it disappears from the "still an open question" list. If you need further assistance please edit your question accordingly or ask a [Follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I've seen you interpreted the answer from percusse to [How can I plot two lines in the same style (using cycle lists) with pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67772/how-can-i-plot-two-lines-in-the-same-style-using-cycle-lists-with-pgfplots) wrongly. You should not add the plots for one Group and then for the next Group and so on. You should add the first plot of all Groups, then the second and so on:

```
\addplot 1 from Group 1
\addplot 1 from Group 2
\addplot 1 from Group 3
\addplot 1 from Group 4 ... then
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-<number of Groups>}
```

But this can be made into an environment, see if this works for you (note that to get the legend right just add legends to the first plots, like below):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcounter{plotscount}\setcounter{plotscount}{0}
\newcommand*{\nextplots}{\stepplots\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-\theplotscount}}
\newenvironment{groupofplots}[1]{\def\stepplots{\addtocounter{plotscount}{#1}}}{\setcounter{plotscount}{0}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:2, samples=10]
      % First plot of each group
      \begin{groupofplots}{2}
        \addplot {1*x+1};\addlegendentry{Style 1}
        \addplot {2*x+1};\addlegendentry{Style 2}
        % Second plot of each group
        \nextplots
        \addplot {1*x+2};
        \addplot {2*x+2};
        % Third plot of each group
        \nextplots
        \addplot {1*x+3};
        \addplot {2*x+3};
      \end{groupofplots}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

In fact you can use `cycle multi list` just as you mentioned:

```
cycle multi list={color\nextlist [N of]mark list}
```

A drawback of this method is the legends, I couldn't get it to work but with the inputs from [Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95441/stefan-pinnow) in the comments below it's possible to provide empty legends for the plots which have the same style (with the exception of one, of course).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-1:2,
        samples=10,
        cycle multi list={color\nextlist [3 of]mark list}]
        \addplot {1*x+1};
        \addplot {1*x+2};
        \addplot {1*x+3};
        \addplot {2*x+4};
        \addplot {2*x+5};
        \addplot {2*x+6};
        \addplot {3*x+7};
        \addplot {3*x+8};
        \addplot {3*x+9};
        \legend{Style 1,,,Style 2,,,Style 3}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that option. I think there's a typo in the legend: it should read: `\addplot {2*x+1};\addlegendentry{Style` **2** `}` but edits must be at least 6 char. Using percusse's suggestion this way is not very handy for me here, to handle the last group with less cases. I'll see if someone comes-up with a `cycle multi` solution.

Comment: Yep, typo! And there you go, `cycle multi list` solution. But without legend... I couldn't solve that one `:(`

Comment: Yep, that's what I feared... `cyle multi` looks like the right way to go, but hacking around gets you where you want.

Comment: Here are my comments to your solution ;) 1. What do you need `\label{style2}` for? And the legend isn't working, because the only thing relevant for `\addlegendentry` is the *order* of that entries and are independent of everything else. That means that they *don't* belong to the previous `\addplot` command. (Give it a try and put them before everything or at the end or whatever you like. Add another `\addlengendentry` anywhere and the *last* one (of the then 4) will show the "red" style.) That is why I prefer the `forget plot` solution. ...

Comment: ... Another solution to the problem would be to not use `\addlegendentry` but `\legend` (or `legend entries=...` in the axis options) and provide empty entries for those that should not show up in the legend, e.g. `\legend{Style 1,,,Style 2,,,Style 3}`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, Oh my, I feel stupid now. I always thought `\addlegendentry` used the last issued `\addplot` `:(`. About the `\label`, it's an attempt to fix the legend problem, I try to get the style of the plot and shove it in the legend via `\addlegendimage`, but now that I understand how `\addlegendentry` works I see that it was a grand mistake. Finally, I didn't know empty legends were ignored, that sure fixes it. Thank's a lot for all your Inputs, I appreciate it very much! `:D` (Btw, your answer is definetely better)

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli, oh please don't feel stupid. PGFPlots has *a lot* of features and it is *impossible* to remember all of them and it is even more impossible to have "side effects" of all the commands in mind. I also learn here at TeX.SX a lot of new stuff. (For example [percusse's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349544/cycle-every-n-plot-in-pgfplots/349602?noredirect=1#comment858471_349602) was either new to me or at least it didn't came to my mind when writing the answer ;)

Comment: And when you want to learn a bit more: Also your `cycle multi list` definition is not doing what you want/think. This you can see e.g. for your `mark=0` which should in general cause an error because there is no mark `0` (zero). In fact here the *values* are ignored and only the *number* of provided `mark`s is accounted for. (You get the same result when stating `mark=bla,mark=bli,mark=blub`.) That is, because the `mark` will be overwritten by the ones provided by the `color` cycle list. If you want them to be effective you have to write them as e.g. `every mark/.append style={mark=+}` ...

Comment: ... But if you want to use just a few that are already declared in the `mark list` cycle list you could also just state `[3 of]mark list`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, that is true! I had a different understanding of `cycle multi list` from reading the Manual. Thank's for clearing that up, I've edited the question so no one is misled by my poor interpretation. Once again, thank you veyr much for taking the time to explain it! `:D`

Comment: @StefanPinnow Indeed, thanks for the hints about the way `cycle multi list` works. That's exactly what I was looking for! I was struggling to understand the documentation. I'll need a little more time to test everything now...

Comment: Sorry, but [my statement](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349544/cycle-every-n-plot-in-pgfplots/349589?noredirect=1#comment858495_349589) was wrong. Also here the `mark`s from the `mark list` aren't used because the `mark`s are not defined inside of `every mark`. So `[3 of]mark list` does the same as `mark=bla,mark=bli,mark=blub` ... (I think that is *intended* because otherwise you wouldn't have a chance to overwrite it again using the short form (`mark=...` instead of `every mark/.append style`).) But now you should be able to create the lists yourself to achieve the desired result ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow, I think the `marks list` *is used* to some extent at least. Take for instance the example by changing the number of `[3 of]` to `N` then the list will cycle every `N` intead of every `3`. I believe taht this is the desired result, as far as the OP has shown concerns for (he/she's not interested in defining the mark list, only that the list style shifts every `N` plots).

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli, that is exactly what I also wanted to state. This was just so that everybody knows that the `mark`s defined in `mark list` are *not* used. Because in my [previous comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349544/cycle-every-n-plot-in-pgfplots/349589?noredirect=1#comment858495_349589) I stated exactly this ...

Comment: I accepted this answer, or rather it's edit, because it shows a clean way to use `cycle multi list`, which can be very handy. Stefan's answer might be a better (more automated) way in many cases.

Answer (score 4):

I think using the `forget plot` feature results in a quite simple solution ...

But because you didn't provide some dummy data table nor did you tell us where your legend entries are coming from I just give an example here, which you can hopefully adapt to your needs. Otherwise please be more specific in the question and edit it accordingly.

For more details on how the solution works, please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
    % just some dummy data
    \begin{filecontents}{test.txt}
        x   g1p1    g1p2    g1p3    g2p1    g2p2    g2p3    g3p1    g3p2
        0.0 0.00    0.25    0.50    1.00    1.25    1.50    2.00    2.25
        0.5 0.25    0.50    0.75    1.50    1.75    2.00    3.00    3.25
        1.0 0.50    0.75    1.00    2.00    2.25    2.50    4.00    4.25
        1.5 0.75    1.00    1.25    2.50    2.75    3.00    5.00    5.25
        2.0 1.00    1.25    1.50    3.00    3.25    3.50    6.00    6.25
        2.5 1.25    1.50    1.75    3.50    3.75    4.00    7.00    7.25
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% to provide the `\ifnumequal' command
% (inspired by <http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5066>)
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=north west,
        ]
            % loop through the groups
            \foreach \g in {1,...,2} {
                % loop through the plots of the group
                \foreach \p [count=\pi] in {1,...,3} {
                    % if the current plot loop is the last one, i.e. no 3
                    % then don't forget the plot and add the legend entry
                    \ifnumequal{\pi}{3}{
                        \addplot table [x=x,y=g\g p\p] {test.txt};
                            \addlegendentryexpanded{g\g p\p}
                    % else forget the plot
                    % (that means, use the current cycle list style without
                    %  increasing the counter and don't account for a legend
                    %  entry)
                    }{
                        \addplot+ [forget plot]
                            table [x=x,y=g\g p\p] {test.txt};
                    }
                }
            }
            % here the same in for your last special case where no
            % "group" loop is needed any more
            \foreach \p [count=\pi] in {1,...,2} {
                \ifnumequal{\p}{2}{
                    \addplot table [x=x,y=g3p\p] {test.txt};
                        \addlegendentryexpanded{g3p\p}
                }{
                    \addplot+ [forget plot]
                        table [x=x,y=g3p\p] {test.txt};
                }
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: (+1) I know in your MWE case it does not matter but didn't you mean to put `\pi` inside `\ifnumequal` instead of `\p`? If not then `count=\pi` is useless...

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli, of course. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: you can also use `\ifnum\p=2\relax .... \else .... \fi` with TeX

Comment: @percusse, thanks for the hint. That is the stuff I don't know anything about :-/

Comment: Spending time here does that to you :P

Comment: @percusse, True. The only hard thing is to *remember* all that stuff ;)